# DDD: How to return validation errors from application services?

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to build a small framework in .NET Core for specific needs following some of DDD principles and I was wondering what's the standard pattern to return validation errors from application layer to api layer.

I've two approaches:

1. Force all app service methods to return fixed structure (e.g. Response<>) and add a property called ValidationErrors in this Response class and fill it from application layer
2. Throw business validation exceptions (e.g. EntityNotFoundException) from application layer and handle them from a centralized middleware

Personally, I'd prefer the first approach but I need your recommendations.

Thanks

Comment: Personally, I find flow execution controlled by typed exceptions to be more OOP than the old technology of returning a result data, especially for DDD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What approach is there for handling and returning errors (non-exceptional and exceptional) in Domain Driven Design entities and aggregate roots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193822/what-approach-is-there-for-handling-and-returning-errors-non-exceptional-and-ex)

Comment: [When to return a Result.Error and when to throw an Exception?](https://patrickroza.com/blog/when-to-return-a-result-error-and-when-to-throw-an-exception/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the first approach too much. You have to make a decision on who's responsibility it is to ensure correct input to a method. E.g. you can validate the input as the first thing that happens in a method. If the input is invalid then you should either throw an ArgumentNullException or an ArgumentException in my opinion and then deal with it later. The correct response from the API should be status code 400 (Bad Request). Use the ActionResult as the return type to return a status code like that.
Also validation can be done by the middleware where you just have check the model state in your controller.
I think the model validation can be linked with other frameworks like Fluent Validation or similar if you prefer that. https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html

You can also call the validator manually in your controller or elsewhere and use the validation result to return the correct http status code