# Is it okay to use attributes and IValidatableObject on domain objects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design

I am used to working with entity objects and now I am switching to DDD principles so I will start using domain objects.

I am used to decorate the properties of my entity objects with attributes such as `RequiredAttribute` or `StringLengthAttribute`. I am also used to implement the `IValidatableObject` on my entity objects.

My question is - is it acceptable to use attributes and `IValidatableObject` on my domain objects? Is it consistent with DDD? Thank you.

Comment: I believe this answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395176/should-i-abstract-the-validation-framework-from-domain-layer/28397201#28397201

Answer (score 2):

Your domain model should work only with business concepts, it shouldn't have any direct relations to DAL or View. Attributes you have applied means that you use your domain model as view model. Create separate viewmodel. Don't use your entity objects which describing your storage model as root class for your domain.Create new classes for your domain objects. Add methods which clear explain business -

`ChangeLastName(string newName)`   instead of `obj.LastName = "Some name"`

`CreateNewPost(string text,string author)` instead of  `obj.Posts.Add(..)`

You can write some extension methods to make mappings, like `ToViewModel`, or do it some else.One interesting design/infrastructure pattern is CQRS & EventSourcing. It allows you avoid mappings, but have some drawbacks (like transactions between aggregates). And last - in most cases simple CRUD operations more suited - fast, simple, easy.

Comment: @AntonPutao Still it did not answer the question. I think the question already implies view models and domain models where view models are map to domain models. In domain layer, it still needs to re-validate whether the property is a valid email address. This can easily be done in view models by decorating the properties with attributes and checking whether the ModelState is valid. Once the view model is validated and you map it to a domain model to be consumed by the domain service, so now the above question, is it okay to use the attributes and IValidateable in the domain models?

Answer (score 0):

From a DDD point of view, the domain model is best kept lean with the use of *exceptions* in your entity’s behavior methods, or by implementing the **Specification** and **Notification** patterns to enforce validation rules.

It can make sense to use data annotations at the application layer in `ViewModel` classes (instead of domain entities) that will accept input, to allow for model validation within the UI layer. However, this should not be done at the exclusion of validation within the domain model.